# Wirtinger's inequality

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality

I was proving this equation in class but I ran into a problem
$$\int_0^\pi u^2dx \leq \int_0^\pi (u')^2dx$$
I have $$0 \leq \int_0^\pi (u' - u \cot(x))^2 dx = \int u'-2uu'\cot(x) + u^2\cot^2(x)dx$$
$$\int_0^\pi 2uu'\cot(X) - u^2\cot^2(x)dx \leq \int_0^\pi (u')^2dx$$
$$\int_0^\pi (u^2)'\cot(x) - u^2\cot^2(x)dx \leq \int_0^\pi (u')^2dx$$
Integrate by parts 
$$ u^2\cot(x)|_0^\pi + \int_0^\pi u^2\csc^2(x) - u^2 \cot^2(x) dx \leq \int_0^\pi(u')^2 dx$$

I know that $u^2\cot(x)|_0^\pi$ is an improper integral

My teacher suggested:
$$^1 \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} u^2\cot(x) = ^2\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{u^2}{\sin(x)} = ^3 \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2uu'}{\cos(x)} = 0$$

Now I understand how the equation would play out if the above happens to be 0 
$$\int_0^\pi u^2(\csc^2(x) - \cot^2(x))dx \leq \int_0^\pi (u')^2 dx$$
$$\int_0^\pi u^2dx \leq \int_0^\pi (u')^2dx$$
done

Where I get in trouble is when I got from 1 to 2 in my teachers suggestion. (2 to 3 makes sense its is just l'hopital's rule.) Why are you allows to convert to $\sin(x)$?

Comment: $\cot(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$ are you sure your equation is right?

Comment: Yes I'm sure thats what he gave us. Which is my problem it doesn't make any sense but I need to turn that term into 0 in order for the equation to work

Comment: It should say $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} u^2\cot(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{u^2 \cos(x)} {\sin(x)}$. The use the fact that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{u^2 \cos(x)} {\sin(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} u^2 \cos(x) \times \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{ \sin(x)}$

Comment: Yes I am fully aware it should but that still leaves the problem of an improper integral and and getting that to 0

Comment: Yes it follows nicely from what the teacher suggested and my previous comment. Remember $\tan(x+\pi)=\tan(x)$ or you can use L'hopital's again for the other limit.